# lambda do count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, lambda

I testing my app for create a new user car, later that the user creates the new car the app must redirect to the user_car_path (I post my routes):

```
user_cars GET    /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                               cars#index
                      POST   /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)                               cars#create
         new_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)                           cars#new
        edit_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id/edit(.:format)                      cars#edit
             user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#show
                      PUT    /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#update
                      DELETE /users/:user_id/cars/:id(.:format)                           cars#destroy
```

so I'm testing my app with this rspec:

```
describe "POST 'create' car" do

describe "car created success" do
  before(:each) do
            @user = User.create!(:email => "foo@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" )
            @car = Car.create!(:brand => "example", :color => "foobar", :model => "foobar", :year =>"2012")
  end

  it "should create a car" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :cars => @car, :user_id => @user.id
    end.should change(Car, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should redirect to the user cars page" do
    post :create, :cars => @car, :user_id => @user.id
    response.should redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)
  end
end
end
```

but i got 2 errors

```
Failures:

1) CarsController POST 'create' car car created success should create a car
 Failure/Error: lambda do
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/car_controller_spec.rb:20

2) CarsController POST 'create' car car created success should redirect to the user cars page
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)
   Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/115/cars/40> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/115/cars/new>.
 # ./spec/controllers/car_controller_spec.rb:27
```

but my app works normally; here is my CarController

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
....

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @car = @user.cars.build(params[:car])
  if @car.save
    redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car), :flash => { :notice => "  car created!" }
  else
    redirect_to new_user_car_path ,:flash => { :notice => " sorry try again :(" }
  end
end
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
  @car = @user.cars.find(params[:id])   
end

....
```

Comment: You've already created that car (persisted it to the database) in your before step, so I guess it won't get created again. Try using `@car = Car.new(...)` instead of `@car  = Car.create!(...)` and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for answer, can you explain me more clear please? where I created the car? I'm getting started in rspec

Comment: @Asantoya17 look in your code yourself where it says `@car = Car.create!` also, read the rails docs and find out why `create!` is different from `new`. This isn't an rspec thing.

Comment: I changed it but now appears this error:Failure/Error: response.should
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :user_id=>#<User id: 154, email: "foo@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$04$SGOwPFq/WTYV4XB3JZNYTetJBb1etCiJqqIlwfi99Cc9...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, name: nil, created_at: "2012-08-03 15:53:39", updated_at: "2012-08-03 15:53:39">, :controller=>"cars"

Comment: this means your `@car.save` is now returning `true` and there is something wrong with your `redirect_to user_car_path(...)` line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the car in the database, rather than just creating a car object in the `before(:each)`. Also you're passing the param as `:cars` rather than `:car`. Finally, I'd also personally use `let`. Try this.

```
describe "POST 'create' car" do

  let(:user) { User.create!(:email => "foo@example.com", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar" ) }
  let(:car)  { Car.new(:brand => "example", :color => "foobar", :model => "foobar", :year =>"2012")}

  it "should create a car" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :car => car, :user_id => user.id
    end.should change(Car, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should redirect to the user cars page" do
    post :create, :cars => car, :user_id => user.id
    # note: car doesn't have an ID, you have to fetch it from the db to get an id
    response.should redirect_to user_car_path(user.id, user.cars.last.id)
  end
end
```

As a final note, you will want to look into [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/)

Then you could do this instead:

```
let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:car) { FactoryGirl.build(:car) } # note: BUILD not CREATE
```

Comment: @Asantoya17 what does 'nothing' mean? Surely it doesn't give you exactly the same errors.

Comment: it doesn't show the same error, now appears   ActionController::RoutingError::action=>"show",:controller=>"cars"

Comment: So my answer fixed your first problem, but you have another problem. Try `redirect_to user_car_path(@user.id, @car.id)`

Comment: I hope you're patient it shows another error...Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: now you have to figure out if `@user` is nil or `@car` is nil and determine why. Wait -> where is the error happening? (also, see my edit for your second spec)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14866/discussion-between-radixhound-and-asantoya17)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the following (:cars => :car and use params that would make the car creation in the controller valid. I am confused why you are creating the car in your spec because this seems to be a test of car creation)

```
  it "should create a car" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :car => {:brand => "example", :color => "foobar", :model => "foobar", :year =>"2012"}, :user_id => @user.id
    end.should change(Car, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "should redirect to the user cars page" do
    post :create, :car => {:brand => "example", :color => "foobar", :model => "foobar", :year =>"2012"}, :user_id => @user.id
    response.should redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)
  end
```

Comment: really I'm learning rspec maybe that's why I could have errors

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your validation fail. To know if it fails do this, before save in your controller :

```
puts @car.valid?
```

If it's false, your test will fail and it's normal. To set to true you can do this:

```
before(:each) do
  ...
  Car.any_instance.stub(:valid?).and_return(true)
end
```

You can also use stubs and mocks to return instances for `User.find` and `Car.build`. See the doc : https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/method-stubs

Comment: ok I solved the first error but still the second error appears "Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/users/115/cars/40> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/115/cars/new>."

Comment: Try to remove the 's' for car in your test. Try to add `puts @car`, and `puts @user` in your controller just to check if they are not nil. You can also go in debug mode in your controller (with pry for example).

Comment: the error changed ActionController::RoutingError::action=>"show",:controller=>"cars"

Comment: This answer will just cause you new problems. You are short-circuiting normal Rails behaviour and forcing `@cars.save` to return `true` when it normally wouldn't. Don't do this.

Comment: I disagree. You want to test the behaviour of your action when the car is saved successfully. With a stub, it's exactly what you are doing. It's isolation!

Comment: @Asantoya17, does `@user` or `@car` is nil?

Comment: @Dougui sure, fine, if you know what you are doing but if you don't understand how stubbing (and Rails) works you are setting up a world of hurt.

Comment: How to test something if don't know what you are doing? Stubbing may be diffuclt at the begining but it's very useful.